# Addition of variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a question about the addition of variance and mean, and I can't seem to have the same answer for variance

Assume A is normally distributed with a mean of 10 mm and a standard deviation of 0.1 mm.
B and C is normally distributed with a mean of 2 mm and a standard deviation of 0.05 mm.
Assume all Random variable are indepedent.
And D=A-B-C
Find the variance and the mean of D

Method 1

E(D)=E(A-B-C)=E(A)-E(B)-E(C)=10-2-2=6

V(D)=V(A-B-C)=C1^2*V(A)+C2^2*V(A)+C2^2*V(A)=1^2*(0.1)^2+(-1)^2*(0.05)^2+(-1)^2*(0.05)^2=0.015

Method 2

Since B=C

E(D)=E(A-2B)=E(A)-2*E(B)=10-(4)=6

V(D)=V(A-2B)=C1^2*V(B)+C2^2*V(B)=1^2*(0.1)^2+(-2)^2*(0.05)=0.02

So the mean gives the same value, however the variance in both cases gives me two different values.I don't understand why? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Where did $B=C$ in method 2 come from?

Comment: B and C have the same mean and standard deviation so I assume they can be combined, as one variable no?

Comment: All variables are assumed to be independent. If $B=C$ then these two are dependent, right?

Comment: Are A, B and C independent? You have to know this information. If they are, then $Var(A-B-C) = VarA + VarB + VarC$.

Comment: All the variable are independent

Comment: I don't understand why saying B=C mean they are dependent?

Comment: @use788888 Because = does *not* mean merely "identically distributed" .  It means $B$ *equals* $C$.  How could they then be independent?

Comment: You're confusing $X_1+X_2$ with $2X$.

Answer (score 1):

By independence, $Var(A-B-C) = VarA + Var(-B) + Var(-C) = Var(A) + Var(B) + Var(C)$. This is correct.

Your method 2 is the incorrect one. The problem is that you assume $B = C$ just because they are identically distributed. This is not the case and it is a mistake that quite a lot of people make when learning probability.

By hypothesis you have that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent. But if $B=C$ then they cease to be independent. Let me illustrate.

By independence, we have (this is the correct calculation)

$$
P(B  >0|C<0) = P(B>0)
$$

But if $B=C$ we'd have

$$
P(B  >0|C<0) = P(B>0|B<0) = P(\emptyset) = 0
$$

Comment: I understand my mistake now. Thank you so much!